# C# calculate Maximum week overtime in given period of time

Tags: c#, datetime, time

My calendar is working with a class Shift which looks like this:

```
public class Shift
{
    public TimeSpan Start { get; private set; } //e.g. 08:00
    public TimeSpan End { get; private set; } //e.g. 17:00
    public DateTime Day { get; } //e.g. 23.3. 2015
}
```

The calendar class looks like this:

```
 public class Calendar
 {
    public Shift[] ShiftsOfEmployee { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Calendar(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        ShiftsOfEmployee = new Shift[Length()];
    }

    public int Length()
    {
        return (EndDate - StartDate).Days;
    }

    public void calculateMaximumOvertime()
    { 
        //TODO 
    }
 }
```

What I am trying to do now is the calculateMaximumOvertime function. I was thinking to do it by calculating the number of weeks(e.g. `int weeks = (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays / 7;`) and then create a List of results one for every week. Then go day by day through `ShiftsOfEmployee` and add the value from every `Shift` (if there is any, otherwise 0) to the corresponding week. Then I would have to go once again through the List of results and pick the maximum. All of this seems to me a bit clunky and I was thinking whether there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your problem into two parts: finding the calendar week and calculating the sums.

You can use [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) to solve the first problem. Then you can use Linq to summarize the data in set fashion.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
var cal = dfi.Calendar;

var shiftWeeks = from se in ShiftsOfEmployee
                 group se by cal.GetWeekOfYear(se.Day, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek)
                   into g
                 select new
                 {
                     WeekNumber = g.Key,
                     Units = g.Sum(s => Units(s.Start, s.End))
                 };

 var max = shiftWeeks.Max(wk => wk.Units);

 public static int Units(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end) { ... }
```

Or if you want the max value per week

```
var shiftWeeks = from se in ShiftsOfEmployee
                 group se by cal.GetWeekOfYear(se.Day, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek)
                   into g
                 select new
                 {
                     WeekNumber = g.Key,
                     Max = g.Max(s => Units(s.Start, s.End))
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the weeks up like that wont work well if the amount  of days is not a factor of seven. A better way of tackling this would be to add each shift into a List and have a counter increment everytime a shift is added, once it reaches 7, create another list representing your next week and reset the counter, and then continue doing this until all shifts have been added to a "week." Then you can do your processing of the largest overtime hours.

```
public void calculateMaximumOvertime()
{
    List<Shift[]> ShiftsByWeek = new List<Shift[]>();
    int count = 0;
    Shift[] adder = new Shift[6];
    foreach (var shift in ShiftsOfEmployee)
    {
        adder.SetValue(shift, count);
        count++;
        if (count == 6)
        {
            Shift[] temp = new Shift[6];
            adder.CopyTo(temp, 0);
            ShiftsByWeek.Add(temp);
            Array.Clear(adder, 0 , adder.Length);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This method does not take into consideration the day of the week, but since days of the week are position based you could design your Array representing a week of shifts with each index representing a day of the week, such that

```
Week[0] = sunday
Week[1] = monday
Week[2] = tuesday
```

and so on.

Comment: I need to have the calendar weeks, even though they are not whole. But you're right about counting the number of weeks that way.

Comment: @Dracke Just have the remaining values in your List be null

Comment: @Dracke pinging with updated answer

Comment: This wouldn't work because the whole schedule can begin with let's say Saturday and end on Tuesday (31 days). Your code would have 5 weeks instead of 6 if I am not mistaken. And not taken from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: @Dracke You're right on that account, I was thinking of weeks numerically instead of having a position, The basic premise in terms of sorting still stands however. You could define certain indexes of the array to be a certain day and add to the correct index based on the day of the shift, and just loop around to the 0 index once it makes its way to Sunday, that's how queues work!